# How to add discovery.type=single-node in my Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I had a node app running Docker with elastic search 7. I want to add this option

> discovery.type=single-node

to elasticsearch services. How can I add that to Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3):

For that, you have to add an environment file **elasticsearch.env** with contents like this.

```sh
cluster.name=my-elasticsearch-cluster
network.host=0.0.0.0
bootstrap.memory_lock=true
discovery.type=single-node # Here you can add that
```

After that, mention the env file in your **docker-compose.yml**

```sh
   // ....

  elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:7.16.2
    ports: 
     - "9200:9200"
    env_file:
      - ./elasticsearch.env
    volumes:
      - ./data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   // ....
```

Answer (score 3):

With plain Docker like this (from the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode)):

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -p 127.0.0.1:9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.2
```

Normall, you don‘t add it to the Dockerfile directly to keep the image usable for single and multi node clusters. Passing in the environment variable does the job.